# List comprehension with else pass

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

How do I do the following in a list comprehension?

```
test = [["abc", 1],["bca",2]]

result = []
for x in test:
    if x[0] =='abc':
        result.append(x)
    else:
        pass
result
Out[125]: [['abc', 1]]
```

Try 1:

```
[x if (x[0] == 'abc') else pass for x in test]
  File "<ipython-input-127-d0bbe1907880>", line 1
    [x if (x[0] == 'abc') else pass for x in test]
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Try 2:

```
[x if (x[0] == 'abc') else None for x in test]
Out[126]: [['abc', 1], None]
```

Try 3:

```
[x if (x[0] == 'abc') for x in test]
  File "<ipython-input-122-a114a293661f>", line 1
    [x if (x[0] == 'abc') for x in test]
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Hi WoodChopper. Actually,  within the for loop, if the condition is met, something is done, if it not met, nothing is done... So the else: pass is redundant.

Comment: @Jblasco: Thanks, my first try was `Try 3` that only but not in proper order as jaco mentioned

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The `if` needs to be at the end and you don't need the `pass` in the list comprehension. The item will only be added if the `if` condition is met, otherwise the element will be ignored, so the `pass` is implicitly implemented in the list comprehension syntax.

```
[x for x in test if x[0] == 'abc']
```

For completeness, the output of this statement is :

```
[['abc', 1]]
```

Answer (score 9):

As a complement to Jaco's answer; it is nice to know about the `filter` command because what you basically want is *filtering* a list:

```
filter( lambda x: x[0]=='abc', test)
```

which returns:

- a list in Python 2
- a generator in Python3 (which may be useful for very long lists since you can later handle the result without overburdening the memory); if you still want a list, just wrap the `filter` function above with a `list()` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I added the if statement after the for loop and it worked for my use case.

```
data = [a for a in source_list if (your_condition)]
```