# pass giving syntax error with ternary operator

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am able to successfully execute the below conditional expression:

```
[i if i%2 != 0 else None for i in range(10)]
```

Output:

```
[None, 1, None, 3, None, 5, None, 7, None, 9]
```

However, I don't want to add `None` and keep only the odd numbers in the list.

To achieve that, I am executing the below code:

```
[i if i%2 != 0 else pass for i in range(10)]
```

The above statement is throwing an error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the problem here with using `pass`?
Why `pass` cannot be the operand of a ternary operator?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List comprehension with else pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691552/list-comprehension-with-else-pass)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `pass` is not returning a value and cannot be the operand of a ternary operator.
Given that your intention is to just get the odd numbers in why don't you simply iterate using a step of two

```py
[i for i in range(1, 10, 2)]
```

Comment: thanks. can you please provide more explanation on why `pass cannot be the operand of a ternary operator`? My goal is to clearly understand the concept here

Comment: Ternary operator returns one of two values (coming from the first and third operand based on the condition defined in your second operand: `A if B else C`. So `A` and `C` have to be some values that would be the result of the operator. In your case instead of C you have `pass` which doesn't provide any value - it's just a syntax element to show that a block is empty.

Answer (score 2):

`[i for i in range(10) if i%2 !=0]` is the filter syntax you're looking for

**It's worth noting if you're doing something like creating odds (I assume your actual use is more complex) I'd use something like `list(range(1,n,2))` where range takes in `range(start, stop, step)`

Comment: nit: The original problem aimed to add just the odd, not the even indices.

Comment: oops, I misread that, updated