# List comprehension in Python for if, elif, pass?

Tags: python

I see syntax for if pass but not finding syntax for if elif pass: [List comprehension with else pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691552/list-comprehension-with-else-pass)

Basically

```
if condition:
    something
elif condition
    something
else
    pass
```

Comment: Aside from the shared keyword `if`, list comprehensions have nothing to do with `if` statements.

Comment: The top answer to that question explains why `else: pass` isn't really needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33691579/765091

Comment: `if` statements and conditional expressions are also unrelated (aside from shared keywords), and a conditional expression used in a list comprehension also has nothing to do with the filter of a list comprehension.

Comment: And `pass` itself is not part of the syntax of an `if` statement ; it's just another statement.

Comment: it's still not working if i omit else. [1 for X in list if X > 1 0 if X < 1]

Comment: @we_are_all_in_this_together Your post is incomplete, e.g. you haven't even asked an actual question. Would you finish it up? Your code doesn't work b/c its syntax is wrong.

Comment: `[(1 if X > 1 else 0) for X in lst if X != 1]` is one way to do what it looks like you want.

Comment: Why are the two conditions the same? Please show a real example, i.e. input and desired output, and if you know how to write the logic you want as a regular for-loop, show us that too please.

Comment: @slothrop Beside the point, but `X != 0` doesn't imply `X > 0 or X < 0`, because of NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `if` at the end of the list comprehension (a filter) in order to completely exclude an item from the list.  For example, if you wanted to do this as a list comprehension:

```
result = []
for i in range(10):
    if i % 2:
        result.append("two")
    elif i % 3:
        result.append("three")
    else:
        pass  # note that you do not actually need this "else" at all
```

you could do:

```
result = ["two" if i % 2 else "three" for i in range(10) if i % 2 or i % 3]
```

Comment: perfect, was looking for the list comprehension form. thanks